# bugzilla - Change Several Bugs at Once

Tags: bugzilla

It seems like there are fields that can not be changed on several bugs at once,
lets say that I can accept that version can not be set on several bugs at once if the belong to different products (because the version is per product).

But can't I change then version / stauts on several bugs that belong to the same component of the same product ?

Answer (score 1):

At least in 4.0.5 you can make bulk changes to version and status at the same time.

Comment: even on bugs that belong to different products ?

Comment: thanks,Thats good information although it does not meet my needs.